# How to set the value of a reactive object (ref) with a value from another reactive object (ref)?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am trying to set the value of a `Form` based on a data in another reactive variable called `Product` but it does not seem to work. The `Form` should set its values to the `Product` data if it is available, and if not then just use `null`.

This is a section of the vue component code:

```
props: {
    ProductID: {
      type: Number,
      default: null
    }
  },

setup (props) {
const Product = ref();

async function loadProduct(ProductID) { // Runs when `props.ProductID` changes using a watcher
      try {
        const Response = await $axios.get(`/api/product/${ProductID}`);
        Product.value = Response.data; // This is an array of data
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
}


 const Form = ref({
      ProductTitle: Array.isArray(Product.value) && Product.value[0].producttitle ? Product.value[0].producttitle : null,
 ProductText: Array.isArray(Product.value) && Product.value[0].producttext ? Product.value[0].producttext : null,
    )}
}
```

In vue devtools I can see that `Product` is populated with data, but the values are never assigned to the `Form` keys - they are just null. If `Product` is reactive and so too is `Form`, why does this not work?

Comment: For others coming here: a `ref` is only reactive for the DOM template. That means when a `ref` value is updated it will show the updated value on the page automatically. It is not however reactive for the code within the the script. To make it reactive there it must be a `computed` property or use a `watch` on it so that when it changes you can fire off your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Form` is only initialized when `setup` is first run, so it's only initialized but won't get updated. If you want `Form` to update when `Product` updates, you can make it `computed` property that relies on `Product`:

```js
const Form = computed(() => ({
  ProductTitle: Array.isArray(Product.value) && Product.value[0].producttitle ? Product.value[0].producttitle : null,
  ProductText: Array.isArray(Product.value) && Product.value[0].producttext ? Product.value[0].producttext : null,
}))
```

Or you can manually update `Form` in `loadProduct`, this way whenever `Product` is reloaded, `Form` will also get updated:

```js
const Form = ref({})
async function loadProduct(ProductID) { // Runs when `props.ProductID` changes using a watcher
      try {
        const Response = await $axios.get(`/api/product/${ProductID}`);
        Product.value = Response.data; // This is an array of data
        Form.value = {
          ProductTitle: Array.isArray(Product.value) && Product.value[0].producttitle ? Product.value[0].producttitle : null,
          ProductText: Array.isArray(Product.value) && Product.value[0].producttext ? Product.value[0].producttext : null,
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer nicely explained. Can you tell me why it does get updated without using computed? Is it only reactive  when using `v-model` on HTML elements?

Comment: It can also get updated when you do `Form.value = ...`, not necessarily `v-model`.