# Why is Javascript object property set to initial value of Vue computed property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, javascript-objects, computed-properties, vue-reactivity

Can somebody help me understand why the javascript object property, `data.test`, is always set to the initial value of the computed property, `square`?  When clicking submit after entering a number in the input field, you will see that `data.test` is always equal to 4. The computed property, however, is working properly as confirmed by the html elements, `anyNum` and `square`.

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michaelvli/g380d4jq/12/)

```
<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'

const anyNum = ref(2)

const square = computed(() => {
  return anyNum.value * anyNum.value
})

const data = {    
  test: square.value <===== Javascript object property is always equal to 4
}

function submitForm() {
  console.log(data)
}    
</script>

<template>
  <p>anyNum: {{ anyNum }} </p>
  <p>square: {{square}} </p>
  <form>    
      <input v-model="anyNum" type="number" >
      <button @click.prevent="submitForm()">
        Submit
      </button>
  </form>
</template>
```

But, if I change the javascript object `data` to a function, then `data.test` captures the computed value of `squared`.  Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michaelvli/qcspawvj/2/).

```
<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'

const anyNum = ref(2)

const square = computed(() => {
  return anyNum.value * anyNum.value
})

const data = () => { 
  return {
    test: square.value  <===== captures the value correct value
  }
}

function submitForm() {
  console.log(data())
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`data.test` is not being reactively updated based on any UI changes.  It has it's initial value set on component creation and is then never updated again.  It's not keeping track of "live" data.  If you want `data.test` to recalculate based on `square.value` changing then `data` will also need to be a computed property:

```js
const data = computed(() => { 
  return { test: square.value }
})
```

the reason your second example works is because as a function it will always rerun/recalculate whenever it's actively called

Comment: I can see that `data.test` is not being reactively updated.  And, I want to now why. The reason that I'm asking this question is because I don't understand why `data.test` is not keeping track of "live" data.  `anyNum` is a ref and a dependency of the computed property of `square`.  Therefore, if `anyNum` changes, then `square` should also be recalculated.  And, if `square` is recalculated, then why is `date.test` in my first example not reflecting the expected value?  Why do I need to use a function, whether or not it's a computed property, to return the object with the expected value?

Comment: You absolutely correct that the use of computed property would fix the issue. I just don't understand why the object key, test, is not updated to the most recent value of square.value at the time the submit button is pushed even though const data is plain JS. I think the missing pieces are: 1) const data is evaluated during the setup lifecycle hook, when it is first initialized 2) updating const data requires the use of a computed property, function, or watcher 3) even using plain JS, a function is needed to update data after submit is fired.

Comment: If you want to update your answer to include the above, I'm happy to accept your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Because the square.value is static in the first example, it only evaluates once. The second example, the square.value is dynamic; it will evaluate every time when the data function is called and then go to check the current square.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you read [Reactivity in Depth](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-in-depth.html#reactivity-in-depth) page of Vue documentation. According to that:

> When you assign or destructure a reactive object's property to a local variable, the reactivity is **"disconnected"** because access to the local variable no longer triggers the get / set proxy traps.

So because the `data` variable is a local variable and you did not used `ref` or `reactive` for that, It behaves like normal JavaScript. Do you expect reactivity from **normal JS**?

Comment: Yes, I did see that page in Vue documentation and suspected that destructuring the reactive object by assigning it to the javascript object property may have been the issue.  This helps my understanding.  Do you have a solution to get around the issue?

Comment: In my opinion we don't need to use ** JavaScript objects** in these situations. Using **ref**, **reactive**, **computed** and so on could be enough for us to handle data in a reactive way.

Comment: The solution at this post helped me understand:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68472977/how-to-set-the-value-of-a-reactive-object-ref-with-a-value-from-another-reacti

Not sure if reactivity disconnect due to destructuring has anything to do with the issue.  Thanks!